# Previous Quarter data is not correctly coming in current quarter, if current quarter doesn't have data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

`Actual vs Expected result:

In the above tables, I have the material, year, cost, qtr, qp. I have to fill the qp column with values from previous quarters if current qtr is null. If the previous quarter's value is NULL, fetch the value from it's previous quarter and so on where it is not NULL.

Please help me to get the expected output on Snowflake. Thanks in advance.
It will be helpful if you can share the running code.

I tried above query, but lag function is not working properly and instead of fetching data from previous quarter, it is taking data from previous row. if it is null it is picking null and also not working for duplicate qtr.`

```
q.year,
q.MATERIAL,
q.COST,
q.QP,
q.QTR,
prev_qtr.prev_qtr PREV_QTR,
lag (qp,1)  OVER (partition by material ORDER BY material, q.qtr) as prev_qtr_q,
lag (qp,2)  OVER (partition by material ORDER BY material, q.qtr) as prev_qtr2_q,
lag (qp,3)  OVER (partition by material ORDER BY material, q.qtr) as prev_qtr3_q,
coalesce(QP,prev_qtr_q,prev_qtr2_q,prev_qtr3_q) as new_qp,
prev_qtr.prev_qtr PREV_QTR,
prev_qtr.prev_qtr2 PREV_QTR2,
prev_qtr.prev_qtr3 PREV_QTR3
from QP q
join PREV_QTR prev_qtr
on q.qtr = prev_qtr.Qtr
WHERE MATERIAL = 'PLASM2673.R3'
``
`
```

Comment: Show data example and desirable output.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.